# Battle Pass Deadpool challenge not working properly

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I got the battle pass and for some reason, I can't complete week 3. I broke the toilets and found the plunger and now it won't go any further. The Deadpool icon in the battle pass section is still lit up yellow which is also ! outside battle pass as well. I tried to click it and it won't go away.

I'm on my Switch, so if anyone has any idea what's going on or if this is a glitch and I have to wait to Friday, someone let me know.

Comment: Oh that's friggen great. So it's a glitch and no one at EPIC is looking at this. LOVELY.

Comment: What is complaining about it here going to do? If anything you should file a support ticket with Epic Games so that they can at least be aware of the issue.

Comment: @senpai Well, I was making sure it wasn't just a SWITCH issue, so I guess we just have to wait and see.

Answer (score 2):

This is a glitch, I'm also on Switch and on Reddit I read others also have this problem on other consoles. So I think we just need to wait.

Comment: It’s on the Xbox and Pc as well